# Any working example of compiling a DLL in wxWidgets

Tags: dll, wxwidgets, compilation, sample

I have found some examples of how to compile a DLL in wxWidgets but none of them compile in wxWidgets 2.8.9

Examples, such as, http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Creating_A_DLL_Of_An_Application (here some of the download links don't even work, such as, http://www.frogmorecs.com/dl/fromdll.zip). Even the code at this forum http://wxforum.shadonet.com/viewtopic.php?p=5964#5964 does not compile.

Even the latest sample from the official wxWidgets SVN (http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxWidgets/trunk/samples/dll/) does not compile with the latest build of wxWidgets.

someone help!

Comment: I just updated `trunk` from SVN, and both the library and the DLL sample built and run flawlessly. Make sure you clean all and have an up-to-date `setup.h`. Anyway, this is way too broad for SO (specific questions that can actually be answered work much better here), consider deleting this question and asking on the wx-users mailing list or on a wxWidgets forum instead. If you still can't get the sample to build, that is.

Comment: I contribute to a couple of projects that do this okay. Can you tell us what specific problem(s) you are having?

Comment: ok here is the output for samples/dll from Visual C++ 2008 Express on windows Vista using the trunk build of wxWidgets:

Comment: <pre><code>------ Build started: Project: my_dll, Configuration: DLL Release Win32 ------
Compiling...
cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
my_dll.cpp
.\my_dll.cpp(208) : error C3861: 'wxDISABLE_ASSERTS_IN_RELEASE_BUILD': identifier not found
.\my_dll.cpp(208) : error C3861: 'wxDISABLE_DEBUG_LOGGING_IN_RELEASE_BUILD': identifier not found

Comment: `Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\pavitar\Desktop\wxDLL\wxDLL\vc_mswudll\my_dll\BuildLog.htm"
my_dll - 2 error(s), 2 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: ok let me just update that. Now I am getting linker errors:
<code>
my_dll.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl wxEntry(struct HINSTANCE__ *,struct HINSTANCE__ *,char *,int)" (__imp_?wxEntry@@YAHPAUHINSTANCE__@@0PADH@Z) referenced in function "unsigned int __stdcall `anonymous namespace'::MyAppLauncher(void *)" (?MyAppLauncher@?A0xb5a53ad7@@YGIPAX@Z)</code>

Comment: <code> my_dll.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall wxEvtHandler::Connect(int,int,void (__thiscall wxEvtHandler::*)(class wxEvent &),class wxObject *,class wxEvtHandler *)" (__imp_?Connect@wxEvtHandler@@QAEXHHP81@AEXAAVwxEvent@@@ZPAVwxObject@@PAV1@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall MyDllApp::MyDllApp(void)" (??0MyDllApp@@QAE@XZ)
vc_mswudll\my_dll.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
my_dll - 3 error(s), 73 warning(s)
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
</code>

Comment: Please see my proper and colourful post at http://wxforum.shadonet.com/viewtopic.php?p=115360#115360

Answer (score 2):

this is how to do it:

1. download rapidsvn
2. create a directory on your computer named "whatever"
3. start RapidSVN
4. go to Repository->Checkout...
5. enter url http://svn.wxwidgets.org/svn/wx/wxWidgets/trunk/
6. select the folder you created as destination directory
7. hit ok
8. once finished, go to the directory and see BuildSVN.txt
9. now build the samples/DLL

it should all work!